# How to prove convergence of $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx}$ without evaluating it

Tags: calculus, integration

How to prove convergence of $\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx}$ without evaluating it. Since $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, there is no problem around zero. But how to show the convergence as the limit goes to $\infty$?

Using integration by parts we can write $$\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx}=\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_1^{c}{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx}=\lim_{c \to \infty}[\frac{-\cos(x)}{x}]_1^{c}-\lim_{c \to \infty}\int_1^c\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}dx$$

The second term can be managed by comparison since $$\int_1^c\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}dx \leq \int_1^c\frac{1}{x^2}dx$$ which is convergent.

But how do you manage $\lim_{c \to \infty}[\frac{-\cos(x)}{x}]_1^{c}=\lim_{c \to \infty}[\frac{-\cos(c)}{c}] + \cos(1)$?

Comment: Squeeze theorem.  $-\dfrac1c \le \dfrac{\cos c}c \le \dfrac1c$ for all real values of $c \ne 0$.

Comment: You break it up into intervals of $\pi$ length, and then show that that you have these for a convergent alternating series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your last question in your post:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac{\cos c}c=-\lim_{c\to\infty}\,\frac1c\cdot\cos c=0$$

since the last is the limit of a function whose limit zero times a **bounded** one.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sin{x}}{x} = 0$. Because the sine oscillates between being positive and negative, we can divide the integral up into 'chunks', on each of which the function is either wholly positive or wholly negative. If the integral exists, then this will be equal to the series of these 'chunks'. Then, by the alternating series theorem, the series (which equals the integral should it exist) converges - the terms go to zero monotonically, for sine is bounded and $\frac{1}{x}$ goes to zero monotonically.

Comment: What series?${}$

Comment: @tilper Should've mentioned that - edited it now to (hopefully) make it clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Why is the integral on the chunks decreasing in absolute value?

Comment: @ZainPatel I thought that was rather evident, but cleared that up as well.

Comment: To address @ZainPatel's comment - you need to add that the integral on the chunk is decreasing in absolute value.  The reason being essentially that when you move to the next interval, the $|\sin x|$ part stays the same but the $1/x$ part decreases.

Comment: Just having terms going to zero is not sufficient to apply the alternating series theorem - consider the series where $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for $n$ odd and $a_n = -\frac{1}{2^n}$ for $n$ even.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Going to 0 doesn't imply it's monotonic - which the alternating series theorem needs.

Comment: That was a really stupid mistake of mine - thank you both for reminding me!!

Answer (score 0):

Integration by parts gives
$$\int_0^N\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx
=\left[\frac{1-\cos x}{x}\right]_0^N+\int_0^N\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx
=\frac{1-\cos N}{N}+\int_0^N\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx.$$
So
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx
=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\,dx.$$
This last is a convergent integral.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^\infty \frac {sin x}{x} dx = \int_0^\pi \frac {sin x}{x} dx + \int_\pi^{2\pi} \frac {sin x}{x} dx +\cdots$

or $\sum_\limits{i=0}^{\infty} \int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi} \frac {sin x}{x} dx$

$\frac {\sin x}{x}\le 1$ for all $x$

$\int_0^\pi \frac {sin x}{x} dx < \pi$

$|\int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi} \frac {\sin x}{x} dx|< \frac {\pi}i$

$\lim_\limits {i\to\infty} \frac {1}{i} = 0$

$|\int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi} \frac {\sin x}{x} dx| < |\int_{(i+1)\pi}^{(i+2)\pi} \frac {\sin x}{x} dx|$

The sign is alternating.

We have passed the alternating series test.